# i m not able to resolve this link error,(during compile time)

Tags: static-linking

asus@asusLaptop:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/chapel/1.33.0/libexec/examples$ chpl -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 hello3-datapar.chpl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: Make Binary - Linking

asus@asusLaptop:~$ ls /usr/lib32 | grep -i stdc++
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6.0.32
asus@asusLaptop:~$ ls /usr/lib | grep -i stdc

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt install build-essential`?

Comment: How did you install `clang-15`? If you installed the Ubuntu `clang` package from the repositories, then it should have automatically installed the `libstdc++6` as a dependency. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: According to the [chpl man page](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/1.14/usingchapel/man.html), the `-L` argument should "Specify a C library search path on the C compiler command line." That's not what you're doing.

Comment: did this sudo apt install build-essential  but 
ubuntu version20.04. 

asus@asusLaptop:~$ clang-15 --version

Command 'clang-15' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install clang-15

asus@asusLaptop:~$ sudo apt install clang-15
[sudo] password for asus: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang-15

how to install clang in ubuntu 20.04